# How to understand the assembly below?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
     __asm__ __volatile__ (

            "movl 0x4(%ebp), %eax \n"

            "addl $15, %eax \n"

            "movl %eax, 0x4(%ebp)"

     );
```

I know `%eax` stores the return value,but what's `%ebp` here for?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your function's prolog looks like this:

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
...
```

%ebp would be the register storing the base pointer (also called a frame pointer).  The base pointer is where the current stack frame starts in the stack.  As in x86 the stack grows downwards, locals are referenced as a negative offset from %ebp.  Parameters and the return address are referenced by positive offsets from %ebp. The value in %ebp points at the caller's %ebp value on the stack (which was pushed by the prolog).  This effectively forms a linked list of base pointers that can be used to "walk" the stack.  Note: this assumes each stack frame has a base pointer; there is an optimization called Frame Pointer Omission (FPO) that frees up %ebp for other uses.

So given a function with that prolog and if it was called with a call instruction (i.e. the caller's return address was pushed onto the stack), then 0x4(%ebp) would store the return address because it was the last thing pushed onto the stack before the callee's prolog executes.  Therefore, your code snippet would cause the next instruction to execute after the callee returns to be 15 bytes from the end of the caller's call instruction, instead of the next instruction after the call.

Edit: my numerous edits thus far have been to better explain my answer.

Comment: +1 makes perfect sense, but the code feels extremely brittle!

Comment: @Martin: indeed, it would appear to make assumptions about the caller (weird to say the least).  Of course, without the full code, we can only really speculate about what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

`ebp` is frame pointer. ebp along with esp marks the stack frame of current process.

0x4(%ebp) is actually is return address, the address to which function to return after this call gets over.

Check the stack frame in this picture.

[image]

Comment: So the stack frames are allocated from low memory to high memory?

Comment: Its architecture dependent. High to low is most common. in x86 its high to low.

Comment: But why the disasembly shows the code is always executed from low to high?  `0x0000000000400498 <main+0>: push   %rbp
0x0000000000400499 <main+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp`

Comment: Thats not stack. What you are saying in address of instruction. Instruction pointer will move from low to high. Only stack will move from High to low.

Comment: @Zimbabao,so the image in your answer must not be for x86,right?As it seems to be it's `low->high`.

Comment: Image is from high to low, green part is not allocated, part with some info is written is under use.

Comment: @compiler: in addition to Zimbabao's good diagram, check out Raymond Chen's "digression" on this blog entry: blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/09/10138401.aspx. Unfortunately, there's no diagram, but Raymond talks about what a function prolog/epilog looks like, how the stack grows from high address to low address, and about the frame pointer. Note: his assembly is in the Intel syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The `%ebp` register points to the current *stack frame* where the function parameters and local variables are stored. That code is accessing a value at offset 0x4 from %ebp (what that value represents is not shown).

Comment: can you help elaborate the image in @Zimbabao's answer?

Answer (score 0):

ebp  is a base pointer. Function params stored in stack, first in stack lies return address, so (if we using 32 bit machine) 0x4(%ebp) points to first param of function.